# Where can I find some good 3D character artists?

Tags: 3d, blender

I am searching for 3D artists for a 3D iPad game. Is there a good place in the net, where I could find one? He or she should have created game models before.

Comment: If you're on a low budget and can't afford to pay for an artist, before you even begin to search for someone willing to work for free you have to make sure you have a playable demo first, or even most of the game done using programmers art and placeholders. This will greatly increase the chances you'll find someone willing to collaborate with you.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your budget, you could try contacting professional 3D artists at sites dedicated to 3D art. Two big ones are:

- [Daz3D](http://www.daz3d.com/i/)
- [Renderosity](http://www.renderosity.com/)

There's also a "Renderotica" for more *naughty* stuff, but I'm not going to link it here ...

A cheaper variant could be looking through modding sites for games for both art and artists. Two I can recommend are:

- [Mod DB](http://www.moddb.com/)
- [TES Nexus](http://www.tesnexus.com/) and its sister sites

Finally, you can always look for nice objects at Google's [3D Warehouse](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/) and contacting the artists of the models you like.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net). You can always find good freelance artists there looking for jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on an Android 2D game that uses 3D model animation frames for its animation (i.e. I'm not manipulating 3D models in real-time, just playing back previously captured frames).

I found a lot of my 3D models on TurboSquid.com, many of which were free and a handful I payed maybe $25 to $35 dollars for.

Depending on what kind of stuff you are looking for, there are a ton of free and low priced art already available.

Good Luck